# How to check statistically significant relationship between images and the values stored in the CSV file?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, image-processing

I am trying to perform a regression task with CNN. I am using some images as the predictors, and the independent variable is coming from a CSV file.

The images are sets of satellite images and the csv file corresponds to crop growth. My aim before going through CNN is to find out if the values within csv file correlate with image channels. The main question is which image channels are more effective/significant to predict the crop growth.

Since I have large number of  image channels, I would like to know first if I can relate the images with values stored in the CSV file. Can someone suggest which technique I can use to check if there is a statistically significant relationship between the image channels and the CSV file?

So, this way I can reduce the dimensionality/the number of image channels, and only utilize those channels which are mostly correlated with the values stored in the CSV file.

Comment: *"to check if there is a statistically significant relationship"* It is not entirely clear what you are doing. Why can't you use CNN for this regression task?

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus please check the updated question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The term statistical significant in the expression *"a statistically significant relationship"* only quantifies the strength of the relationship and it doesn't specify it much. It is still not clear what sort of relationship you are trying to search for. For what relationship are you trying to find out whether it is significant? Looking for 'a relationship' between images and a CSV file is very broad.

Comment: What are you trying to predict? If the images are the predictors, then what is the role of the CSV file?

Comment: *"How to check statistically significant relationship"* An answer could be: "train the model on data with and without a certain parameter and test/validate it to see whether the prediction error decreases by a sufficient/significant amount" (see [cross validation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics))). But probably you want to have some smarter algorithm than this straightforward but time-consuming trial and error approach. For a more specific method you need to explain more specifically what you are doing.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus That's true. I am looking for a smarter algorithm. please see the update question.

Comment: A few more questions. **1** Does it matter that the data is coming from a CSV file? Could you explain why you added this? (Because you explicitly mention it I am imagining that it is a very large file and your are looking specifically for methods to implement the regression on a very large data table. Or maybe you just use CSV in place of a 2d matrix?)

Comment: **2** *"find out if the values within csv file correlate with image channels"* How do you express/define 'correlate' here? Is there some way to process you images at a lower level than a CNN, e.g. just use the average amount of green which turns the image in a numeric value, such that you can use a Pearson correlation? We can not answer how you should do this correlation. It seems to be domain specific and not something 'statistical'. Potentially you could have some approach of training the CNN on a smaller amount of data and evaluate the correlation before the final large scale CNN?

Comment: The data coming from csv file is used here to train the CNN model. After successfully building and training the model, it should be able to receive an unseen image and predict the crop growth value with respect to that image. The csv file contains a column of values. Can you give an example about a potential approach here: "Potentially you could have some approach of training the CNN on a smaller amount of data and evaluate the correlation before the final large scale CNN?"

Comment: *"The csv file contains a column of values. "* Speaking about a CSV file is confusing. If you just have a single variable with only a single value to predict per image then just say that you have a single variable. Speaking about a CSV file makes it confusing (with me it generates associations that something more complicated is going on).

Comment: *"it should be able to receive an unseen image and predict the crop growth value with respect to that image."* I can not see the connection how this relates to 'multiple image channels'? In one place you speak about a *single* image based on which you make a prediction. In another place you speak about *multiple* image channels.